# How do I set a project to not compile in any active configuration in Xamarin?

Tags: configuration, build, compilation, xamarin

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to setup a configuration for a project in Xamarin to not compile (build). I've done some Googling on the subject, but couldn't find very much information due to the lack of documentation on anything that doesn't involve mobile development for Xamarin. :P Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify. You are using the Xamarin Studio IDE? You have multiple projects in a solution and don't want them to all compile?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Xamarin IDE and do have multiple projects under one solution. My desire is to disable specific projects from compiling. I know you have the ability to do so in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

In the Solution Explorer, right click the solution and go to options. In the Build/Configurations section, click the Configuration Mappings. There you can include or remove projects from different configurations, not only the active one.

You can also follow the guided tutorial from here: http://xmonodev.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/setting-the-active-configuration-in-xamarin-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this issue.
**First, You will remove project in project solution on solution pane.**
[remove project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A90TV.png)
**And then you have to insert project to your solution, again.**
[insert project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbsT6.png)
Perhaps it will work.